# Display an image after resizing

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to resize and image with the following function:

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}
```

After creating the function, I am trying to display the image after resizing by using this code but it is not working:

```
<?php

    $img = resize_image('../images/avatar/demo.jpg', 120, 120);

    var_dump($img); //The result is: resource(6, gd)
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $img;?>"/>
```

PS: There is no problem with the inclusion of the function

Comment: Where is the instruction you use to store the image, or you want to resize it  'on the fly'? You're just trying to print an image resource identifier expecting to get a image, that's not goint to work... You might need a folder to store the temporal images you resize and delete them after finished their function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly output an image that way. You can either:

1. Save the image to disk and enter the URL in the image tag.
2. Buffer the raw data, base64 encode it, and output it as a data URI (I wouldn't recommend this if you're working with large images.).

Approach 1:

```
<?php
$img = resize_image('../images/avatar/demo.jpg', 120, 120);
imagejpeg($img, '../images/avatar/demo-resized.jpg');
?>
<img src="<?= 'www.example.com/images/avatar/demo-resized.jpg' ?>"/>
```

Approach 2:

```
<?php
$img = resize_image('../images/avatar/demo.jpg', 120, 120);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($img);
$output = base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
?>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= $output; ?>"/>
```