# Display resized image programatically without creating another image on server

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

Is there any library or script which would allow me to display the resized version of an image programmatically? without actually creating another resized image and saving it into the server?

I am looking for something like this, ie:

```
<img src="script.php?image_path=/mysite.com/public_html/img/my_image.jpg&new_width=300&new_height=100" />
```

Is it possible? Does it exist?
I hope I am making sense here...
Thank you very much for your help! :o)

Comment: You can create a php script that resizes images, passing the filename as a get parameter, and displaying the image using imagejpeg or imagepng while setting the second argument of either of the output functions (filename) to NULL and setting the headers properly. However, just as a comment, you'd be putting a lot of strain on the server if you have too many users and it will increase load times in your pages if you have too many images. Regardless, this would be an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display an image after resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165036/display-an-image-after-resizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cloudinary to programmatically resize images based on the resolution of the viewing device. All you need to do is basically mention the height and width parameters and it transforms the image on-the-fly:

```
<?php echo cl_image_tag("my_image.jpg", 
                        array("width" => 100, "height" => 150, "crop" => "fill"));
 ?>
```

For more examples on re-sizing that suit your specific use-case, you can refer the the documentation here: 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_manipulation#resize_crop_and_thumbnails

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.